# Can't find d3dcompiler_43.dll for DirectX programming

Tags: c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, directx, windows-runtime

I am trying to learn DirectX Programming.  But I have hit a snag.

**I seem to be missing this file: d3dcompiler_43.dll**

I have installed (in this order):

1. Visual Studio 2012
2. Windows 8
3. Windows Phone 8 SDK
4. Windows 8 SDK

I figured I need a DirectX SDK, but this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says I do not:

> Starting with Windows 8, the DirectX SDK is included as part of the Windows SDK.

Should I just install the DirectX Distributable?  I am worried that will give me the dll but I will be missing other things too...

Here is my exact error I am getting:

> Unable to load DLL 'd3dcompiler_43.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

**Update:**  I ran `dxdiag` and it says I have DirectX 11 installed...  Not sure why I can't make this work.

Comment: Try downloading DirectX Distributable, cant hurt.

Comment: @ForgiveMeI'mAN00b - All the Dists that I can find are for 2010 and DirextX 9...

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812 will get you directx11 SDK. The 2010 dists are for DirectX11 I think.

Comment: @Aaron, I had the same error, and that was how I fixed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx

It says:

> Any project that uses run-time shader compilation must have D3DCOMPILER_46.DLL copied to the local executable path for the project. This DLL is available in this sub-directory of the Windows SDK installation under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.0\Redist\D3D\arch where arch is x86 and x64.

Comment: Funny thing is, on windows 8 I get this error on windows 8.1 I don't get it.
File is missing from folder.  
So the information is not completely right.

Comment: Im curious, did this actually solve your problem in reality, or was this a "best fix you could find"? In my case, it was giving the exact same error code (which is calling for 43.dll, not 46.dll), and newer versions would not fix it. I had to actually go back and get 43.dll from an old directX install.

Answer (score 5):

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx) for details about D3DCompile and how you distribute various versions of it...

In short:

- #43 and prior is deployed by the legacy DirectX End-User Runtime Redist (aka DirectSetup).
- #46 is installed by VS 2012 / Windows 8.0 SDK and is deployed 'side-by-side' with your Win32 desktop app
- #47 is installed by VS 2013 / Windows 8.1 SDK and can be deployed 'side-by-side' with your Win32 desktop app, but it is also included with the Windows 8.1 OS.

Comment: This greatly helped me, as it was specifically the #43 this error was calling for. [Other users running into the same problem can download legax Directx End-User Runtime Redist from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35).

Comment: Got this error with d3dcompiler_43.dll on MonoGame on Windows 10. Installing the DirectX End-User Runtime solved that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have Chrome installed, worth a butchers in here:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\26.0.1410.64
```

Comment: Downvoter - this answer *is* useful. I got the dll from here and it saved downloading the whole of Windows SDK.

Comment: As of Chrome 65 x86, it comes with `d3dcompiler_47.dll`, not `d3dcompiler_43.dll` :(

Comment: Too late - the DX June 2010 redist install was running while you were responding, and now the program in question works fine :) .  ([This](https://demozoo.org/productions/185629/), by the way - a demo just released over Easter weekend, and well worth a watch)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the latest DirectX
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35

Comment: the particular version OP is missing will not install from the link you provide. I sourced the file back to "Legacy DirectX" from 2010. The latest versions do not include it, anymore, and as I have since tested, it makes a big difference.