# Where should the DirectX stuff be after installing the Windows 8 SDK?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, directx, directx-11, winapi

I installed the Windows 8 SDK (which is supposed to include the DirectX SDK).

But my directX stuff is not working (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544367/cant-find-d3dcompiler-43-dll-for-directx-programming#comment18549503_13544367) about that).

But on a seperate question, I wanted to ask where all the DirectX SDK stuff is supposed to be after you install the Windows 8 SDK.

If the answer is "lots of places" then lets go with this one file: `d3dcompiler_43.dll`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx

It says:

> Any project that uses run-time shader compilation must have D3DCOMPILER_46.DLL copied to the local executable path for the project. This DLL is available in this sub-directory of the Windows SDK installation under %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.0\Redist\D3D\ where  is x86 and x64.